# Error Creating DB in SQLServer Management Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Im creating the school project http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399731.aspx from asp.net when I run the sql in management studio to create the database it says I cannot create it in the master.
I get this error "permission denied in database 'master'". I follow the link for this error but there is no documentation

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Create failed for Database 'School'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1447.4+((KJ_RTM).100213-0103+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Database&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 262)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.1399&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=262&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------


===================================

Create failed for Database 'School'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1447.4+((KJ_RTM).100213-0103+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Database&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database.Create()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabaseData.DatabasePrototype.ApplyChanges(Control marshallingControl)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabase.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)
```

Comment: You need to the dbcreator permission for creating a database... Are you logged in as DBAdmin??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are login with windows credentials or with "sa" account? I recomend using server login (with sa account and pass you provide in instalation process) not windows authentification.

if you succes login with windows authentification under master you have security options. Expand Security->Logins and you will see all user including sa. Right click on it and select propierties. There you have options to set password.

Comment: could you give me the steps do this cos I don't know much about all this server and login setup. I just set it up the default way did'nt prompt me about any account etc. I logged on using my computer name and then clicked connect

Comment: Do I have to re-install SqlServer?